# Listar o produto mais vendido por dia no BD de uma loja

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso listar o produto mais vendido por dia na loja, mostrando a descrição, o tipo e o dia.

Até onde cheguei:

```
SELECT Data, MAX(QtdVenda) as Vezes_Que_Foi_Vendido, IDProduto, Fabricante, tipo, nome
from vendas INNER JOIN produtos on QtdVenda=
    (Select Max(QtdVenda) from vendas order by data)
where produtos.ID = vendas.IDProduto group by data order by data;
```

Saída:

```
+------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| Data       | Vezes_Que_Foi_Vendido | IDProduto | Fabricante | tipo       | nome |
+------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| 2017-07-08 |                    10 |        15 | SAMSUNG    | Smartphone | S9   |
+------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------+------------+------+
```

Estrutura das minhas tabelas:

```
mysql> select * from produtos;
+------+------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID   | Nome                   | Fabricante | Quantidade | VlUnitario | Tipo       |
+------+------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    1 | Playstation 3          | Sony       |        100 |       2000 | Console    |
|    2 | Core 2 Duo 4GB RAM 500 | DELL       |        200 |       1900 | Notebook   |
|    3 | XBOX 360 120 GB        | Microsoft  |        350 |       1300 | Console    |
|    4 | GT-1620 QUAD BAND      | SAMSUNG    |        300 |        500 | Celular    |
|    5 | iPHONE 4 32 MB         | Apple      |         50 |       1500 | Smartphone |
|    6 | Playstation 2          | Sony       |        100 |        400 | Console    |
|    7 | Wii 120 MB             | Nintendo   |        250 |       1000 | Console    |
|    8 | S7                     | SAMSUNG    |        100 |       1500 | Smartphone |
|    9 | J7                     | SAMSUNG    |        300 |       1000 | Smartphone |
|   10 | iPHONE 5 32 MB         | Apple      |        150 |       2000 | Smartphone |
|   11 | Core 2 Duo 8 GB        | DELL       |        100 |       2500 | Notebook   |
|   12 | Playstation 4          | Sony       |        250 |       2500 | Console    |
|   13 | Notebook               | DELL       |        200 |       3000 | Notebook   |
|   14 | Ultrabook              | DELL       |        100 |       5500 | Ultrabook  |
|   15 | S9                     | SAMSUNG    |        300 |       2500 | Smartphone |
+------+------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
15 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from vendas;
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| IDVenda | Data       | Cliente        | IDProduto | QtdVenda | Desconto |
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+
|       1 | 2017-07-08 | Carlos Santana |        15 |       10 |       50 |
|       2 | 2017-07-09 | Ana Maria Melo |         7 |        1 |      100 |
|       3 | 2017-07-09 | Fernando Silva |         8 |        1 |       70 |
|       4 | 2017-07-09 | Fernando Souza |        13 |        2 |      150 |
|       5 | 2017-07-10 | Luis Gama      |         3 |        1 |       50 |
|       6 | 2017-07-10 | Arthur Filho   |         7 |        2 |      100 |
|       7 | 2017-07-10 | Fernando Silva |        12 |        1 |       50 |
|       8 | 2017-07-10 | Fernando Souza |        15 |        3 |      200 |
|       9 | 2017-07-12 | Ana Maria Melo |         1 |        3 |      200 |
|      10 | 2017-07-13 | Cassio Moreira |         5 |        1 |       50 |
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    v.data, max(v.qtdVenda), p.nome, p.tipo from vendas as v
inner join
    produtos as p on produtos.id = vendas.idProduto
group_by
    v.data
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Creio que o que você se refere é group by e não group_by.